# Trouble using parsejson for calculated field in amazon quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

i have a column with json data, from which i have to get a value for a key. for example,

```
{'address':{ 'name' : 'villa', 'number' : '9876786987'}}
```

for the data i have to fetch the
value for name.
I tried using parse json in calculated field like,

```
parseJson({address_data},"$.address.name"),
parseJson({address_data},"$.0.address.name")
```

which did not work and is throwing syntax error, Could anyone please help me finding what im doing wrong here?